# Testing *ngIf show/hide component dependent on data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a show/hide data component. 
Without its data (currently undefined), a simple block of text is displayed.

However when i then feed the component with data, the first block should become hidden whilst the second block that consists of the list of data in a table **should** become visible, however null is being returned (withDataBlock).

Therefore tests errors on the last expect of the test, even though i add `fixture.detectChanges()` method beforehand.

component:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChanges, OnDestroy, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AccountSearchService } from './../../services/account-search.service';
import { ISearchResult, ISearchResultContentItem, IContentItemStatus } from './../../entities/search.entity';
import { SortByPipe } from './../../pipes/sort.pipe';
import { FilterPipe } from './../../pipes/filter.pipe';
import { CapitalisePipe } from './../../pipes/capitalise.pipe';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-account-list',
    templateUrl: './account-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./account-list.component.scss'],
    inputs: ['inputSearchTerm']
})
export class AccountListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    private searchTerm: string = undefined;
    private sortByParam: string = "name";
    private initialText = "Perform search above to view results below.";
    private subs: Subscription = undefined;
    private searchResults: ISearchResult = undefined;
    private accountsCollection: Array<ISearchResultContentItem> = undefined;

    @Input() public set inputSearchTerm(value: string) {
        this.searchTerm = value;
    }

    constructor(
        private _accountSearchService: AccountSearchService
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (!changes.inputSearchTerm.firstChange) {

            let curValue = changes.inputSearchTerm.currentValue;

            this.subs = this._accountSearchService.SearchAccounts()
                .subscribe((response: Response) => {

                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        this.searchResults = <ISearchResult>response.json();
                        this.accountsCollection = <Array<ISearchResultContentItem>>this.searchResults.content;
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.subs)
            this.subs.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div id="accounts-list" class="accounts-list">
        <div id="accountsListNoData" class="row" *ngIf="!accountsCollection">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p>{{ initialText }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="accountsListWithData" class="row accountsListWithData" *ngIf="accountsCollection">
            <div class="col-12">

                <div class="row" *ngIf="searchTerm">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p>You searched for: "{{ searchTerm }}"</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right" *ngIf="searchResults">
                        <p>{{ 'Page: ' + (searchResults.page+1) + ' of ' + searchResults.totalPages }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row" *ngIf="(accountsCollection | filter: searchTerm).length === 0">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p>No results found</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12" *ngIf="(accountsCollection | filter: searchTerm).length > 0">
                        <div class="table-responsive">

                            <table id="accountsListTable" class="table">
                                <thead class="thead-brand">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <a (click)="sortByParam='id'" title="Sort by Account ID">Account ID</a>
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <a (click)="sortByParam='name'" title="Sort by Account Name">Account name</a>
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <a href="#" title="Sort by account number">Account number</a>
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <a href="#" title="Sort by account sort code">Sort code</a>
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <a (click)="sortByParam='balance'" title="Sort by balance">Balance</a>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr *ngFor="let account of accountsCollection | filter: searchTerm | sortBy: sortByParam">
                                        <td scope="row">{{ account.id }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <strong>{{ account.name | capitalise }}</strong>
                                        </td>
                                        <td [innerHTML]="account.identifiers[0].accountNumber"></td>
                                        <td [innerHTML]="account.identifiers[0].sortCode"></td>
                                        <td [innerHTML]="'&pound;' + account.balance"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AccountListComponent } from './account-list.component';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SortByPipe } from './../../pipes/sort.pipe';
import { FilterPipe } from './../../pipes/filter.pipe';
import { CapitalisePipe } from './../../pipes/capitalise.pipe';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AccountSearchService } from '../../services/account-search.service';
import { ISearchResult, IContentItemStatus, IIdentifiers, ISearchResultContentItem } from './../../entities/search.entity';

describe("AccountListComponent", () => {
    let component: AccountListComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountListComponent>;
    let debEl: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AccountListComponent, CapitalisePipe, SortByPipe, FilterPipe
            ],
            imports: [HttpModule],
            providers: [AccountSearchService]
        }).compileComponents()
    })

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountListComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        debEl = fixture.debugElement;
    })


    it("should initialise the component", () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });
    })

    it("should show accounts-list__noData block without data", () => {

        expect((<any>component).searchResults).toBeUndefined;

        fixture.detectChanges();

        //test initial instruction text
        let alEl = debEl.query(By.css(".accounts-list"));
        let withoutDataBlock = <HTMLDivElement>alEl.nativeElement.querySelector("p");
        expect(withoutDataBlock.textContent).toEqual((<any>component).initialText);
    })

    it("Show accounts-list__withData block with passed in data", fakeAsync((done) => {

    let alEl = debEl.query(By.css(".accounts-list"));
    let withDataBlock = <HTMLDivElement>alEl.nativeElement.querySelector("#accountsListWithData");

    expect((<any>component).searchTerm).toBeUndefined;
    expect(withDataBlock).toBeUndefined;

    const testAccounts = <ISearchResult>{
        content: <Array<ISearchResultContentItem>>[
            {
                id: "A02017NU",
                name: "1010 SOFTWARE LTD",
                balance: "46.91",
                currency: "GBP",
                status: IContentItemStatus.ACTIVE,
                identifiers: <Array<IIdentifiers>>[
                    {
                        type: "SCAN",
                        accountNumber: "00001232",
                        sortCode: "000000"
                    }
                ],
                customerId: "C0200098",
                externalReference: "Account 1"
            }
        ],
        page: 0,
        size: 15,
        totalPages: 407,
        totalSize: 60960944
    };

    component.inputSearchTerm = "software";

    const inputSearchTerm = <SimpleChange> {
        currentValue: "software",
        firstChange: false,
        previousValue: undefined
    }

    component.ngOnChanges({ inputSearchTerm });
    fixture.checkNoChanges();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    done();
    expect((<any>component).searchTerm).toBeDefined;


}))

})
```

Error:

```
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule/AccountListComponent.ngfactory.js'.', '; Zone:', '<root>', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', DOMException{stack: 'Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule/AccountListComponent.ngfactory.js'.
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:2990:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.proto.(anonymous function) [as send] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1394:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/victoroyea/Documents/Sites/modulr/modulr/node_modules/source-map-support/browser-source-map-support.js?f894bb45358bceea281c12011b12863c67d3942c:111:263)
```

Comment: The code is complex and needs a way to reproduce the problem - working stackblitz, plunker, repo, etc. *Therefore tests errors on the last expect of the test* - the question isn't specific on what works and what does not, this is the reason why it gained close votes. *//ERRORS HERE* - which ones?

Comment: I suspect that there is testing methodology problem. This is integration test because you didn't mock `accountSearchService`. When a test fails, you never know at which point it failed. That's why unit tests exist. In unit tests, every unit but one that is tested should be mocked. accountSearchService should be mocked. This way if a thing doesn't work, you can deduce the reason why it doesn't.

Comment: @estus... i've updated the question and homed into cause complete with current error.

Comment: Do I need to fake the subscription as well? If so how would one do this? (jasmine spy?) since component.ngOnChanges({ inputSearchTerm }); already called?

Comment: The error means there are problems with performing real XHR request (and it shouldn't be performed in unit tests). No, the subscription shouldn't be faked, it's the subscription you're testing here. You're injecting real AccountSearchService. It should be a mock, something like `{ SearchAccounts: jasmine.createSpy('').and.returnValue(Observable.of({ status: 200, json: () => {..mockedData..} }) }`. The fact you need to go low level and mock `Http` response suggests that AccountSearchService doesn't provide enough abstraction over Http, you could move `res.json()` and `status` to SearchAccounts.