# How do I test *ngIf blocks in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am developing an Angular 5 app, in which i have a component where two blocks of HTML reside, block 1 and block 2.

Initially block 1 consisting of the intro text is displayed, and block 2 is hidden. When the component is then fed with data via an @Input, block 2 now listing the data becomes visible, and block 1 becomes hidden. Now the next step is to test the component.

I attempted to test the component by @Input-'ing' data, however block 2 is still not displayed, (even though i manually apply the "detectChanges()" method).

How do i test *ngIf states (switch on/off) of the component in order to test??

You could refer to the code in this post that describes my unsuccessful attempt.
[Testing *ngIf show/hide component dependent on data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518436/testing-ngif-show-hide-component-dependent-on-data)

Comment: *How do i test *ngIf states (switch on/off) of the component in order to test* - by mocking component data that is used in ngIf expressions and calling component `detectChanges()`. *I attempted to test the component by @Input-'ing' data* - how? The question isn't specific enough and lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus
*"by mocking component data that is used in ngIf expressions and calling component detectChanges()"*
I did just that updated with mock data... ((<any>component).accountsCollection = testAccounts.content;)
Please take a look at my code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518436/testing-ngif-show-hide-component-dependent-on-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing \*ngIf show/hide component dependent on data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518436/testing-ngif-show-hide-component-dependent-on-data)